# Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking recording double countings

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm implementing enhanced ecommerce through Google Tag Manager (GTM) using the dataLayer and I'm having issues with some values that are being reported double to the reports.

The value reported double is 'Product Checkouts' that can be seen in the 'Product List Performance' report in Google Analytics (GA).

I've spent a lot of time on this and I'm sure, I don't have one of the following common pitfalls:

- There is absolutely only one GTM snippet in the code.
- When the user refreshes the page the value isn't reported again (as after refreshing nothing is pushed to the dataLayer)
- Triple checked for spelling mistakes
- Pushed the values to the dataLayer before GTM snippet

In the image below I'm showing an example;
First, the add_to_cart is reported properly; only once.

While the checkout is reported twice every single time for every product (doesn't matter how many products reported)

[image]

This is the list of Tags in GTM:

1

Tag type : Universal Analytics

Track type : Pageview

Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true

Use Data Layer: true

Trigger: event equals gtm.dom

2

Tag type : Universal Analytics

Track type : Event

Event Category: Ecommerce

Event Action: Product Click

Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true

Use Data Layer: true

Trigger: event equals productClick

3

Tag type : Universal Analytics

Track type : Event

Event Category: Ecommerce

Event Action: Add to Cart

Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true

Use Data Layer: true

Trigger: event equals addToCart

4

Tag type : Universal Analytics

Track type : Event

Event Category: Ecommerce

Event Action: Remove from Cart

Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true

Use Data Layer: true

Trigger: event equals removeFromCart

5

Tag type : Universal Analytics

Track type : Event

Event Category: Ecommerce

Event Action: Checkout

Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true

Use Data Layer: true

Trigger: event equals checkout

6

Tag type : Universal Analytics

Track type : Pageview

Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: no

Trigger: All Pages

Comment: Do you have two tags that are activated for the same type of event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an issue with the configuration of your tags. You have  first tag as;

```
1
Tag type : Universal Analytics
Track type : Pageview
Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true
Use Data Layer: true
Trigger: event equals gtm.dom
```

This above tag is going to fire on all pages (including the final confirmation page). While you have another tag that you have configured to fire on final confirmation page that is.

```
5
Tag type : Universal Analytics
Track type : Event
Event Category: Ecommerce
Event Action: Checkout
Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true
Use Data Layer: true
Trigger: event equals checkout
```

So actually the tag 1 is duplicating "all" the data including the transaction one, transaction one is more visible as you are checking this. For debugging purpose you can turn off the 1st tag, and than test you should be able to see single transaction instead of duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the problem. That happens when following the documentation exactly as they recommend https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#details

Answer (score 1):

This is a pitfall of the official docs, using pageview to send ecommerce data will indeed duplicated the pageviews and interact with which events is sent when. To avoid this, better use only custom events as trigger and code when they fire.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of anther event that fires using a tag with enhanced ecommerce settings on

Comment: Thanks @Nouran Raduf I've edited the task to include a list of the tags in GTM. Hope it makes the question more clear